# Unable to read post form value in Golang with htprouter

Tags: http, go

I'm new to Golang and trying to get a basic http app running using the *httprouter* API.  I've hit a wall with reading posted form data, despite following the advice given [in another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284299/5081731).

Here's my code (minus irrelevancies):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)


func main() {
    r := httprouter.New()
    r.POST("/sub", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        r.Header.Set("content-type", "text/html")
        err := r.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Error: %s</h1>\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Submitted message!</h1>\n<p>-%s-</p>\n", r.PostFormValue("msg"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", r)
}
```

In the output, where I should see `-hello-`, I just see `--`.  When I inspect the http request in Firefox, in the Form Data panel, I see `msg:"hello"`, so why is  `r.PostFormValue("msg")` returning a blank string?

Comment: Maybe you could show the actual request? Btw: Your `r.Header.Set("content-type", "text/html")` is nonsensical on the request; it probably should go on the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Volker for pointing out an error.  When I commented out the line  `r.Header.Set("content-type", "text/html")`, the problem was resolved.  Perhaps that was the issue, or perhaps there was some issue with the IDE (LiteIDE) caching an old version of the code.  In any case, I can now read the posted value.